# Knockout.js binding handler for Wysihtml5

Tags: data-binding, knockout.js, wysihtml5

I'm trying to bind a knockout observable to the Wysihtml5 editor using [this binding handler](https://gist.github.com/rix0rrr/4110437), but can't get it to work. Someone that can point me in the right direction?

```
ko.bindingHandlers.wysihtml5 = {
    init: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var control = $(element).wysihtml5({
            "events": {
                "change" : function() {
                    var observable = valueAccessor();
                    observable(control.getValue());
                }
            }
        }).data("wysihtml5").editor;


    },
    update: function (element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
        var content = valueAccessor();

        if (content != undefined) {
            var control = $(element).data("wysihtml5").editor;
            control.setValue(content());
        }
    }
};
```

Simplified JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/f8pG9/5/).

Comment: Can you be a little bit more specfic? What is not working? What should happen in your sample JSFiddle?

Comment: @nemesv The `ko.observable` `ExampleText` should display in both the `<span>` and the `<textarea>`, and changes to the texarea should be reflected in the span (and of course in the underlying viewmodel).

Comment: A few reference was missing from your fiddle mainly the  bootstrap-wysihtml5.js from https://github.com/jhollingworth/bootstrap-wysihtml5 but otherwise it looks fine: http://jsfiddle.net/RJ3Rb/

Comment: Great, it works just like expected in your fiddle! I'm not using bootstrap in my project, so I didn't think those files were necessary for Wysihtml5 to work. Thanks for the quick response, @nemesv